# How to filter a List using Java 8 stream and startwith array of values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, startswith

I have 2 Lists, the one contains a list of numbers and the other a list of names. I have prefixed the names with a number from the first list, followed by an underscore. I want to filter the second list based on all the numbers found in the first list.

What I have tried.

```
List<String> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
numberList.add("1_");
numberList.add("9_");

List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
nameList.add("1_John");
nameList.add("2_Peter");
nameList.add("9_Susan");

List<String> filteredList = Stream.of(numberList.toArray(new String[0]))
                .filter(str -> nameList.stream().anyMatch(str::startsWith))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The code above runs with no error, but the filteredList is empty. Clearly I am doing something wrong.

The filteredList should contain only:

1_John

9_Susan

Comment: To create a stream from a Collection just use the existing API as `Stream.of(numberList.toArray(new String[0]))` => `numberList.stream()`. While you're actually iterating on the incorrect list using the streams. It should be the second list to iterate on and first used to filter in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call `startsWith` on the wrong `String`s (for example, you test if `"1_".startsWith("1_John")` instead of `"1_John".startsWith("1_")`).

You should stream over `nameList` and use `numberList` for the filtering:

```
List<String> filteredList = 
    nameList.stream()
            .filter(str -> numberList.stream().anyMatch(str::startsWith))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

P.S. `Stream.of(numberList.toArray(new String[0]))` is redundant. Use `numberList.stream()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternate to Eran's solution, you can also use a combination of `removeIf` and `noneMatch` as follows:

```
List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>(nameList);
filteredList.removeIf(str -> numberList.stream().noneMatch(str::startsWith));
```

Comment: Thanks, I will also give this a try to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt to give a solution could be to use `contains` , though the actual implementation of `startsWith` and `contains` are different but in OP case both will fetch the **same** result.

```
List<String> strList = nameList.stream().filter(s->numberList.stream().anyMatch(s::contains)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Output**:

> [1_John, 9_Susan]

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
numberList.add("1_");
numberList.add("9_");

List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
nameList.add("1_John");
nameList.add("2_Peter");
nameList.add("9_Susan");
```

**Following is the correct code:**

[image]

**Your code uses the following:**

[image]